# Save increased variable angular. Like save every 2 seconds instead of sending every click as save-requests to server

Tags: typescript

I have a website with a counter. I want to save the quantity amount number to a server.

.html

```
    <button class="button button-primary" (click)="clickPickPlus(quantity)">+</button>
    {{ quantity }}
    <button class="button button-primary" (click)="clickPickMinus(quantity)">-</button>
```

.ts

```
async clickPickPlus(quantity : number) {
     quantity++;

     await this.save(quantity);
}

async clickPickMinus(quantity : number) {
     quantity--;

     await this.save(quantity);
}
```

But i want to save every 2 seconds or so, so that not every click generates a save.

Comment: `onClick` call a function that has `setTimeout` in it's body. Pass `clickPick` as the callback to the timeout

Comment: I get a save every time anyway, only difference is that all saves are delayed

Comment: You can use a boolean flag indicating if already waiting for the timeout, in order not to prepare a new sending. Or you could use the return value of `setTimeout` to cancel the timer. There are many solutions.